# How to make LoadingCache to call load() in a non blocking fashion()?

Tags: java, caching, guava, nonblocking

I'm using Google's guava library to create my cache. I'm going with LoadingCache interface for it. Below is the code snippet,

```
public class BlockedURLs {
private static final long MAX_SIZE = 1000;
private static final long CACHE_DURATION = 2;

private static LoadingCache<String, ArrayList<String> > lruBlockedURLCache;

BlockedURLs() {
    lruBlockedURLCache = CacheBuilder
            .newBuilder()

            .maximumSize(MAX_SIZE)

            .expireAfterWrite(CACHE_DURATION, TimeUnit.HOURS)

            .build(new CacheLoader<String, ArrayList<String>>() {
                @Override
                public ArrayList<String> load(String s) throws Exception {
                    return BlockedURLLoader.fetchBlockedURLListFromRedis(s);
                }

            });
}

public static ArrayList<String> getBlockedURLList(String domain) {
    return lruBlockedURLCache.getUnchecked(domain);
}
}
```

As I understand it, if I call getBlockedURLList for a domain for which the List is not cached it will load the list first and then return the result. But, that's not the behaviour I want.

If the key isn't present in cache, I expect cache to call it's load function but I want to do it asynchronously. So, if the key wasn't present, I'll say I can work with no key in cache this time and move on, but I want the key to be present next time I try to fetch it. Essentially, I want to call load() in non-blocking fashion. That is cache.get() should not wait till the result is fetched from load() first.

Answer (score 1):

This is the example from [Caches Explained](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained)

```
// Some keys don't need refreshing, and we want refreshes to be done asynchronously. 
LoadingCache<Key, Graph> graphs = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()        
   .maximumSize(1000)        
   .refreshAfterWrite(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)        
   .build(new CacheLoader<Key, Graph>() {              
      public Graph load(Key key) { // no checked exception                
         return getGraphFromDatabase(key);              
      }       

      public ListenableFuture<Graph> reload(final Key key, Graph prevGraph) {        
        if (neverNeedsRefresh(key)) {                  
            return Futures.immediateFuture(prevGraph);                
        } else {
            // asynchronous!                  
            ListenableFutureTask<Graph> task = ListenableFutureTask.create(new Callable<Graph>() {                    
                public Graph call() {                      
                    return getGraphFromDatabase(key);                    
                }                  
            });                  
            executor.execute(task);                  
            return task;                
        }
          }
        });
```

Comment: I guess you misunderstood the problem. I'm not calling load() first. Also, I don't want to pre-populate the cache either because there may be many entries and I don't want to put all data in cache if there's no request coming for it.

Comment: The pattern used is... if cached, return; otherwise create, cache and return. Sorry I can't be of help, there is no native way in Guava to do what you are trying (that I am aware of). Is your fetchBlockedURLListFromRedis that expensive?

Comment: Yep, I'm afraid it is expensive operation.

Comment: Do you know all the keys? Perhaps you could pre-load the cache with empty lists and then make use of reload() which can re-fetch asynchronously, while returning the "stale" value (in this case, the pre-populated empty list.

Comment: Alternatively, return null or an empty list from load() and rely on reload() to get the expensive values asynchronously.

Comment: I like your last approach, where would I call reload() in that case? Inside, load() only I assume.

Answer (score 1):

In your situation, you could choose to return a signal value from load() that indicated absence, and then populate the cache in the background.

```
public Optional<List<String>> load(final Key key) {
    exec.submit(some-task-that-calls Cache.put(K,V));
    return Optional.absent();
}
LoadingCache<String,Optional<List<String>>> cache = ...
```

So in this case, you bypass the default behaviour of waiting until a key is available by providing a signal value immediately.  When the URL is retrieved, the task should call Cache.put(K,V) making the data available for subsequent calls.

You could just use a ConcurrentMap directly, although by using LoadingCache, you'll only start one background task per key.